# big step semantics for loop, I keep getting an infinite loop

Tags: haskell, for-loop, semantics, infinite-loop

Although this is only part of the code, can some decipher why i am getting an infinite loop
This is how the big step semantic is suppost to look like

[image]

```
eval (For iexp c, s)
    |(bEval (Compare Leq iexp (IConst 0), s)) = s
    |otherwise = eval (For n' c, s')
    where
        s' = eval(c,s)
        n' = (IBin Minus iexp (IConst 1))
```

Comment: The parentheses around `bEval (Compare Leq iexp (IConst 0), s)` are not required (and confuse my mental parser ;-)). There are more non-idiomatic parentheses and missing spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The infinite loop most probably comes from a different part of your code. The snippet you gave  looks correct and--with the necessary types and functions suitably mocked out--terminates.

Perhaps you do not evaluate subtraction correctly? Another possibility is that `bEval` does not work correctly.

This is a good use-case for `Data.Trace`, which provides a `trace` function for debugging. This is just like using print statements to debug in any other language. (Internally, it uses `unsafePerformIO`.)

The `trace` function takes a string and an expression; it prints the string and returns the expression. There is also a `traceShow` function which uses `show` on its argument before printing.

You can use it to print out the intermediate values as the loop gets executed. I suggest something like this:

```
eval (For iexp c, s)
  | condition `traceShow` condition = s
  | otherwise = n' `traceShow` eval (For n' c, s')
  where condition = bEval (Compare Leq iexp (IConst 0), s)
        s' = eval(c,s)
        n' = (IBin Minus iexp (IConst 1))
```

This will print out the condition and value of the counter at each step. This should help you figure out where the loop is coming from. If it doesn't, you can move the trace statements around, using them the same way as I have here.